# <class 'ValueError'> ValueError('_getfinalpathname: path too long for Windows') for PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract the data from pdf using Tessearct and PyPDF2. for the last page I am getting an error: **<class 'ValueError'> ValueError('_getfinalpathname: path too long for Windows')**

I can see that the text extracted from the PDF was getting appended in the Path. Not sure why that was happening and how to stop it.

Here is my code below.
Using Python 3.11.2

```
import pytesseract
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from PIL import Image

# Path to the PDF file
pdf_path = "file_.pdf"

# Open the PDF file
pdf = PdfReader(open(pdf_path, "rb"))

# Extract text from PDF pages
extracted_text = ""
for page_number in range(0,len(pdf.pages)):
    print("processing Page " + str(page_number))
    page = pdf.pages[page_number]
    page_text = page.extract_text() # Extract text from the page
    extracted_text += page_text
    with open("data.txt", "a", encoding="utf8") as dataFile:
        dataFile.write(page_text)

# Perform OCR on extracted text
final_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(extracted_text)

# Print the extracted text
with open("OCRdata.txt") as OCRData:
    OCRData.write(final_text)
print(final_text)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf

Answer (score 0):

You are using

`pytesseract.image_to_string`

wrong.

The syntax is `pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))`.